# RAD XE5 Studio and Android widget

Tags: android, delphi, widget

I searched this question, but found nothing.

I hope, I did not create a duplicate thread.
I am new in RAD Studio XE5 and mobile development...
Is it possible to create a widget for Android in RAD Studio? Is there some tutorial?

Thanks all!

Comment: for what i understand, Android widgets might only be native applications. I mean "Android-native". Delphi instead compiles "hardware-native" applications that are not "Android-native" and i never heard anyone managed to turn one into a widget.

Comment: Thank you. It means, if you want to create widget, only eclipse, only java, only hardcore. Or Android Studio. i understood.

Comment: Well, i'd prefer Scala. Just fail to find time to try it seriously. But there also is Oxygene. It produces native (as in Android-native) applications too. There also is Lazarus that was used to make open-source games for Android before FireMonkey and iOS support appeared in Delphi XE2. I don't know though, if the back-end for those games was CPU-native ARM binaries or Android-native JVM+DEX, i suspect the former option just like with Delphi. *PS. lurk-speak in my StackOverflow? oh, deer...*